# Galois Theory for Differential Equations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, galois-theory, functional-equations

Consider the set of algebraically primitive functions:

that is the set of functions who can be created through some recursive expression involving arithmetic operators. Example

$$y = x +1$$
$$y = x^2$$
$$y = 2^x$$
$$y = 3^{x + \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + x^2 + \log_5(x)}}$$

all these functions have the property of being based on arithmetic, algebra, and extensions of those.

Consider the Differential Equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y$$

It is clear that the solution to this diff EQ cannot be expressed using any version of the functions above. Unless we create a number $e$ and consider the set of expressions above that can also have the number $e$. Then the solution:

$$C_1e^x$$

becomes accessible and can be used to solve this equation.

This process of defining new terms to solve differential equations is analogous to create ultra-radicals to solve high order polynomials. Is there some abstract algebraic way of looking at differential equations, determining if they are solvable given certain tools, and if not, what additional numbers/functions need to be defined to make them solvable?

Comment: How do you define $2^x$ or $\log_5 x$ in the first place without the natural $\log$ or $e$? At any rate, there is something called "Differential Galois Theory."

Comment: Moreover, what rule as described in your post prohibits the use of $e$ as a base? Are you looking at bases and exponents exclusively in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory (by the way this is the first search result when you enter "galois theory for differential equations" into google).

Comment: The key is that all my expressions exclusively use a combination of integers and expressions of the form +, *, ^, (and hyperoperators) plus their inverses. e cannot be expressed using any of these (the closest we get is $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$ but that involves another number $\pi$ which cannot be expressed by itself either. Thus one of these numbers needs to be created to progress since they cannot be recursively assembled from the integers and arithmetic operators/inverses without the use of a limit.

Comment: van der Put and Singer have a book with the same title as the subject for this question (there might be a "linear" in there somewhere, I don't recall).

Comment: … which can be found [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~singer/papers/dbook2.ps)

Comment: do u have a pdf version of that^?

Comment: I would love it if somebody would provide a really really elementary/babyish explanation of differential Galois theory, relating it to the elementary ode theory we know, as a means to motivate wading through a book on this subject - dreams...